# Trying to create a glossary but my computer can't find the necessary files

Tags: glossaries

There have been similar questions, but I can't find one that solves my exact problem. I'm having trouble getting the glossary to "print" at the end of my document.

Here's my LaTeX markup:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries


\begin{document}

  \newglossaryentry{computer}
{
  name=computer,
  description={is a programmable machine that receives input,
           stores and manipulates data, and provides
           output in a useful format}
}

 \glsaddall
\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I went into Terminal (I'm using a mac) and typed:

```
makeglossaries *the location*/test
```

and it gives me

```
Error in line 2:

(require "test.xdy")
ERROR: Could not find file "test.xdy" !

***Call to xindy failed***
Check '*the location*/test.glg' for details
```

The test.xdy file is located in the same location as everything else, so I don't understand what the problem is. I really don't know what to do with test.glg, which is a file I don't know how to open.

I'm not new to LaTeX, but I'm new to most of the fancier features and I'm not particularly computer savvy, so please assume a minimum amount of knowledge.

Comment: Try `cd *the location*` and then `makeglossaries test`. That worked for me with `test.xdy` produced from your code.

Comment: Ah! It still didn't like it with xindy, but I removed that and then my code worked once I used your commands in Terminal. Thank you so much!

Comment: That's weird. It worked fine for me just as it was. Maybe a different version of the programmes. Anyway, I'm glad it worked. I guess you need to be in the same directory as your files for `makeglossaries` to work its magic!

Comment: Yeah, I guess so... I didn't even know about "cd" until you told me. I'm assuming it limits the search on one's computer to the specified location. Anyway, I don't need xindy, so all is very well.

Comment: You can use the `-d` option when invoking `makeglossaries` to indicate the directory that contains the `.xdy`/`.ist`, etc files, although it's easiest just to `cd` to it. I recommend you move the `\newglossaryentry` command to the preamble. See [Drawbacks With Defining Entries in the Document Environment](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs).

Comment: @Charles0349 `cd` is short for 'change directory to'. So basically you are switching to the directory with the files before running `makeglossaries`.

Comment: @Nicola Talbot great I will do that. Thank you both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Converting the comments into an answer.)

You need to either change to the directory containing the files using `cd` before you run `makeglossaries` or use the `-d` option when running `makeglossaries`.